# Why is setTimeout("otherFunction()",2000) wrong?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am a newbie to java script and currently reading John Resig's Pro javascript techniques . While explaining closure he refers to calls like  `setTimeout("otherFunction()",2000)` as instances where new JS developers have problems . I could not understand why this is a problem ? Can some one explain please ?In this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp I am seeing a call like `var t=setTimeout("alertMsg()",3000);` which looks similar to me .

Comment: You've found one of several examples of why w3schools is not a good site to learn from. For more, see http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's *not* "wrong", it's just not necessarily "right", and it's certainly not recommended.

The [`setTimeout()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)'s first parameter can be a string or a function reference / function expression.

If you pass a string it will be slower because effectively you are doing an `eval()` which is [not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!). More important than speed though is that the scope in which the code in the string executes may not be what you are expecting (and may not be the same in different browsers).

By passing a function reference / function expression instead these problems can be avoided.

The "right" syntax for your example is:

```
setTimeout(otherFunction, 2000);
```

Note there are no parentheses after `otherFunction` - if there were it would call `otherFunction()` immediately and pass the return value from that function to `setTimeout()`.

If you need to pass parameters to your function you can wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    otherFunction(param1, param2);
}, 2000);
```

That may seem kind of clunky compared to `setTimeout("otherFunction(param1,param2)", 2000)` but again it avoids issues with scope of where `otherFunction`, `param1` and `param2` are defined.

Answer (score 5):

The recommended approach is to use the following:

```
setTimeout(otherFunction, 2000);
```

or a closure:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    otherFunction();
}, 2000);
```

Do not use the overload which takes a string as first parameter because the javascript interpreter will need to parse this string into javascript code.

And yeah, the site you have linked to http://www.w3schools.com is probably one of the worst sites out there to learn programming. It shows exactly what you shouldn't do.

Comment: -1 "Why should I not use strings in setTimeout?" -- "Because the recommended approach is to not use strings."

Comment: @molf, yes, exactly for this reason. You really don't want to force the interpreter parse your strings over and over into javascript code.

Comment: I believe the point that @molf was making is that you didn't explain _why_ strings are not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Because it has to `eval` `otherFunction()` (and hence spawn a new instance of the interpreter) every time. If you provide a reference to the function, `setTimeout` can execute it without the necessity to spawn a new interpreter.

So use:

```
setTimeout(otherFunction,2000);
```

Comment: "spawn a new instance" is exactly the reason, not "not recommended" or so.

Answer (score 1):

Anything enclosed with "" is a string so a JavaScript interpreter will generally need to parse the string.

Parsing the string is unnecessary even if it works.

If we simply use

`setTimeout(alertMsg,3000);`,

the interpreter is not required to do any additional (unnecessary) work, resulting in *better* code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `setTimeout("otherFunction()",2000)`, pass the function directly by doing 
`setTimeout(otherFunction,2000)` is much better. The previous way has to do `eval` the string `"otherFunction()"`.